# pthread_create() and pthread_join() function doesn't work in the same loop

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I've written some code that creates multiple threads and runs these threads on specific cores. But there is a problem in running the code if I place both `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` function in the same loop.

```
for(TN=0;TN<NUM_THREADS;TN++)
{ 

  pthread_create(&thread[TN],NULL,(void*) &hardAffinity,(void*)&CPU[TN]);           

  pthread_join(thread[TN],NULL);
}
```

The problem is that above code doesn't work if I want to run it on separate core of cpu. I think it's because create and join method is in the same loop. It works only if I place each method in a separate loop

Comment: And that problem is ..... ?!

Comment: You create one thread at a time and then wait for it to finish. Clarify what you mean by this: "_How this problem is resolved as threads are being created here but then no further activity is done_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is making both calls pthread_create() and pthread_join() function in separate loops

```
for(TN=0;TN<NUM_THREADS;TN++)

 { 

   pthread_create(&thread[TN],NULL,(void*) &hardAffinity,(void*)&CPU[TN]);           

 }

 for(TN=0;TN<NUM_THREADS;TN++)

 {

   pthread_join(thread[TN],NULL);

 }
```

Comment: What problem are you solving exactly?

Comment: I downvoted this because nobody knows what the problem *is* yet.